# Include SVG layers as steps in beamer

Tags: beamer, animations, svg

I have a `.svg` figure (created with inkscape) with multiple layers and I would like to include them in a beamer presentation so that layers appear progressively.

- slide 1 -> layer 1
- slide 2 -> layer 1+2
- slide 3 -> layer 1+2+3
- ... etc

I could generate multiple `.eps` with the different steps, but as my figure is a growing graph I would have to deal with the boxes, which would be a real pain. Also this doesn't scale well.

Is there any easy/automatic way to generate either a multipage `.pdf` where layers appear progressively (which I could juste include in beamer) or (better) export the multilayer `.svg` to a tikz with time steps ?

Comment: This appears to be about Inkscape rather than TeX related. If so, it may be off-topic here and you might be better off asking it elsewhere. Are you asking about how to export in a certain format from Inkscape? (That's how I read the stuff about turning the SVG into a multipage PDF but I might have misunderstood.)

Comment: I know how to export from inskape in `.pdf`/`.eps` The question is what format could be used to load multilayer graphics in beamer and how to used this layer information to produce multiple slides

Comment: If you can export to the PDF, you could burst the PDF and then include the layers in order in your document.

Comment: As I said in the question, the layers cover different par of the image, which means that the different pdf produced would not be the same size, and aligning them would be a real pain. Also if the number of layer is high (let's say > 100) it would involve doing the same stupid thing over and over -> let's have this process automated -> let's find a good format to pipeline this !

Comment: If there is no common alignment point, yes, it would be a pain. If there is a common alignment point you could use, not so much. The second just requires a loop. If you do it a lot, obviously you might find it convenient to define a macro for the loop. But the alignment is likely to be the real problem if there's no common point you can use. (Different size isn't a problem if, say, they share a common north east point or centre or south west or west or whatever. Absent that, yes, it would be a pain.

Comment: I am not sure I understood your problem correctly, but for me the following workflow works: In inkscape go to the layer with the largest image and select the page size according to it. Then delete/add components and export the images and now they should all have the same paper size

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`\includesvglayer` command](https://github.com/johnyf/latex_packages/blob/master/mycommands.sty#L453) from `mycommands.sty` (a package I've written to group common utilities of this kind).

It calls the Python script [`inkscape2scenes.py`](https://github.com/johnyf/inkscape) (see branch `dev`) that calls `inkscape` to export the combinations of layers defined within the SVG to separate PDF + text overlayed using the `picture` environment within LaTeX (usual PDF+LaTeX export of `inkscape`).

These combinations of layers are then placed in different slides, in order to show them progressively, by advancing through the slides. The possibility of exporting combinations of layers allows picking custom combinations as desired, so that a strict subset relation is not imposed between the layers present in different slides.

`inkscape2scenes.py` is based on [`inkscapeslide`](https://github.com/abourget/inkscapeslide). There is also [`inkslides`](https://github.com/janoliver/inkslides), a rewrite of `inkscapeslide`

Comment: When I run inscape2scenes.py, I get the error`No 'content'-labeled layer`.

Answer (score 4):

The [`export_overlays`](https://github.com/jbohren/beamerscape) script from BeamerScape pretty much does this:

- You can combine a set of layers visible in each output step; you just put the normal beamer-style spec in the layer name inside inkscape (`<1-2,4> Cat Layer`, `<3> Dog Layer`). You should let `export_overlays` control the entire frame (so make your SVG the appropriate aspect ratio to begin with). `export_overlays` will compose the layers with textpos in a .tex file that you can happily `\input{}`.
- If you have a 1:1 mapping of layers to beamer animation steps and then include them using your own `\includegraphics` commands as you normally would
  and ignore the generated `overlay.tex`.

Comment: Welcome! There's a tour you can take if you want to get more familiar with the site, or the Help provides answers to various questions you might (or might not) have. Thanks for posting information about what looks like a useful tool.

Answer (score 2):

Add a text object containing `\pause` in each layer in Inkscape and simply use `\includesvg` in the tex file.
It is like a hack but it works.

This method can also create more complex effects by adding something like `\onslide<2-3>\transfade<2>\transduration<2>{0.75}` in the text objects.

Answer (score 1):

There's a convenient script available at https://github.com/berteh/svg-objects-export which can be used as follows to extract PDF files for each layer of an inkscape-produced SVG file named `image.svg`:

```
svg-objects-export.py --type pdf --xpath "//svg:g[@inkscape:groupmode='layer']" --extra '--export-area-page --export-id-only' image.svg
```

Due to the way that `svg-objects-export.py` names the files (based on SVG ids), you will likely need to rename each generated file from something like `image_layer1.pdf` to `image_layer-1.pdf`, which is a form that will work with the `xmpmulti` class (used below).  [If there's an easier way to get the files properly named, please edit this answer!]

After you have the (renamed) PDF files, you should be able to relatively easily include them in beamer using something like:

```
\usepackage{xmpmulti}
....
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{MyFrame}
    \multiinclude[<+>]{format=pdf}{image_layer}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```